# Jquery keeping tabs selected on each page if page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

i have this HTML Code:

```
<div class="tab-box">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink activeLink" id="tab1">Tab1</a> 
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink" id="tab2">Tab2</a> 
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink" id="tab3">Tab3</a> 
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink" id="tab4">Tab4</a> 
        </div>
```

this lists the tabs...

then each tab is like:

```
<div class="tabcontent" id="tab1-1">
tab1 content
</div>

<div class="tabcontent hide" id="tab2-1">
tab1 content
</div>

<div class="tabcontent hide" id="tab3-1">
tab1 content
</div>

<div class="tabcontent hide" id="tab4-1">
tab1 content
</div>
```

then the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabLink").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        localStorage.selectedTab = $(this).index() + 1;
        tabeId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(this).addClass("activeLink");
        $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
        $("#"+tabeId+"-1").removeClass("hide")   
        return false;     
      });
    });  

    // search for local storage
    if (localStorage.selectedTab) {
      $(".tabLink:eq(" + (localStorage.selectedTab - 1) + ")").click();
    }
  });
```

the jquery above, i have tried to make it so it remembers the last tab selected if the page is refreshed. however, this only works with one page. if i change to view a different page with tabs, it selects a random tab as i cannot find the last one selected because it was on a different page with a different name.

how can i make it remember the last selected tab for each page?

Comment: More than you need, but [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) worth checking out. That combined with `.htaccess`, can make for some really rich tab effects.

Answer (score 0):

What about cookies?

```
document.cookie = "tabId=" + tabeId;
```

then check it:

```
tabId = document.cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie such as `document.cookie = selectedTab` ,

or you can send the value of the selected tab back to the page via an ajax request such as:

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example_page.php", {selectedTab: "3"} );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is really bad. You are just repeating yourself.

```
$(".tabLink").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
```

Just use this

```
$(".tabLink").on("click", function() {
```

The rest of the method, just store the ID of the element.

```
    // Stop the href from functioning
    e.preventDefault();

    // Store the tab identity in localStorage
    localStorage.selectedTab = $(this).attr("id");

    // Toggle the links
    $(this).addClass("activeLink").siblings().removeClass("activeLink");

    // Toggle the tabs
    $(".tabContent").hide();
    $("#" + localStorage.selectedTab + "-1").show();
});
```

and to show the selected tab on load

```
if ($(localStorage.selectedTab).length === 1) {
    $(localStorage.selectedTab).click();
} else {
    $("#tab1").click();
}
```

Try this out with my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/itanex/5sf8p/

Comment: i dont suppose you can do a jsfiddle as its not working for me now - http://jsfiddle.net/KpCFY/1/

Comment: It could be due to jsFiddle not saving across Run events. I would suggest pulling out the code into files and running this naturally.